How to Properly Dispose Unmanaged Resources in ScopedRegionManager with Prism Library in WPF?
I am currently developing a WPF application using the Prism Library. In my application, I am utilizing the ScopedRegionManager in SpecView to manage different views. Some of these views hold unmanaged resources, and I need to ensure these resources are properly disposed of when the view is navigated away from. Typically, I would call the Dispose method to clean up these resources.
However, I have encountered a problem: when navigating away from SpecView which has the ScopedRegion, the OnNavigatedFrom method of the child view holding the unmanaged resources is not called. As a result, I have no indication that the view has left, and the unmanaged resources are retained in memory, causing a memory leak.
Currently, my solution is to call the following code in the OnNavigatedFrom method of each layer's ViewModel:
var parameter = new NavigationParameters();
ScopedRegionManager.RequestNavigate("AlgRegion",
nameof(LeavingView), NavigationFinished,
parameter);


Firstly, is it really causing a memory leak? That term is often used in a very generic way for things that are not memory leaks at all. A memory leak occurs when you allocate memory and then lose access to it to be able to deallocate that memory. If that's not happening then, whatever your issue is, it's not a memory leak.

If you have implemented the IDisposable pattern according to proper convention, the system will release those resources on its own, when the garbage collector runs the finalizer. That will mean they are released later but they will still be released. There are sometimes legitimate reasons that you aren't able to dispose an object explicitly. There may be some way to get the required notification in this case but I'm not familiar with Prism so can't help there.

I doubt that views holding unmanaged resources is sensible design. What unmanaged resources are we talking about? Do your really need a finalizer? I suggest reading When everything you know is wrong by Eric Lippert before implementing one. Also, have a look at this issue over at github: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/7

The root cause maybe the ScopedRegionManager was not deal properly I guess.When the VM is created ScopedRegionManager is built. But  the ScopedRegionManager will not deal with any more. IsNavigationTarget return false, so next time navigating to the View ,another VM is cretated also another ScopedRegionManager,the old ones were left to GC or other mechanism.Worsely I have a chain of ScopedRegionManager,that is  a toply View with a ScopedRegionManager has a child view with another ScopedRegionManager. The unmanaged resource is a VTK 3D display control and a point cloud with a mount of data.

Issue  mentioned by Haukinger will help a lot.

https://qiita.com/thinva/items/70b5bf43b881cc4fe6cf
Info from this page is also helpfull.
